# TensorFlow, losses after training the model are different than losses printed during the last Epoch of Stochastic Gradient Descent.

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to do binary classification on two spirals.  For testing, I am feeding my neural network the exact spiral data with no noise, and the model seems to work as the losses near 0 during SGD.  However, after using my model to infer the exact same data points after SGD has completed, I get completely different losses than what was printed during the last epoch of SGD.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)

# get the spiral points

t_p = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)

x1_p = t_p * np.cos(t_p*2*np.pi)
y1_p = t_p * np.sin(t_p*2*np.pi)
x2_p = t_p * np.cos(t_p*2*np.pi + np.pi)
y2_p = t_p * np.sin(t_p*2*np.pi + np.pi)

plt.plot(x1_p, y1_p, x2_p, y2_p)

# generate data points

x1_dat = x1_p
y1_dat = y1_p
x2_dat = x2_p
y2_dat = y2_p

def model_variable(shape, name, initializer):
    variable = tf.get_variable(name=name,
                               dtype=tf.float32,
                               shape=shape,
                               initializer=initializer
    )
    tf.add_to_collection('model_variables', variable)
    return variable

class Model():
    #layer specifications includes bias nodes
    def __init__(self, sess, data, nEpochs, learning_rate, layer_specifications):
        self.sess = sess
        self.data = data
        self.nEpochs = nEpochs
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        if layer_specifications[0] != 2 or layer_specifications[-1] !=  1:
            raise ValueError('First layer only two nodes, last layer only 1 node')
        else:
            self.layer_specifications = layer_specifications
        self.build_model()

    def build_model(self):
        # x is the two nodes that will be layer one, will input an x, y coordinate
        # and need to classify which spiral is it on, the non phase shifted or the phase
        # shifted one.
        # y is the output of the model
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, 1])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[])
        self.thetas = []
        self.biases = []
        for i in range(1, len(self.layer_specifications)):
            self.thetas.append(model_variable([self.layer_specifications[i], self.layer_specifications[i-1]], 'theta'+str(i), tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1)))
            self.biases.append(model_variable([self.layer_specifications[i], 1], 'bias'+str(i), tf.constant_initializer()))

        #forward propagation
        intermediate = self.x
        for i in range(0, len(self.layer_specifications)-1):
            if i != (len(self.layer_specifications) - 2):
                intermediate = tf.nn.elu(tf.add(tf.matmul(self.thetas[i], intermediate), self.biases[i]))
            else:
                intermediate = tf.add(tf.matmul(self.thetas[i], intermediate), self.biases[i])

        self.yhat = tf.squeeze(intermediate)
        self.loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(self.yhat, self.y);

    def train_init(self):

        model_variables = tf.get_collection('model_variables')
        self.optim = (
            tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
            .minimize(self.loss, var_list=model_variables)
            )
        self.check = tf.add_check_numerics_ops()
        self.sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    # here is where x and y combine to get just x in tf with shape [2, 1] and where label becomes y in tf
    def train_iter(self, x, y):
        loss, _, _ = sess.run([self.loss, self.optim, self.check],
            feed_dict = {self.x: x, self.y: y})
        print('loss: {0} on:{1}'.format(loss, x))

    # here x and y are still x and y coordinates, label is separate
    def train(self):
        for _ in range(self.nEpochs):
            for x, y, label in self.data():
                print(label)
                self.train_iter([[x], [y]], label)
            print("NEW ONE:\n")
    # here x and y are still x and y coordinates, label is separate
    def infer(self, x, y, label):
        return self.sess.run((tf.sigmoid(self.yhat), self.loss), feed_dict={self.x : [[x], [y]], self.y : label})

def data():
    #so first spiral is label 0, second is label 1

    for _ in range(len(x1_dat)-1, -1, -1):
        for dat in range(2):
            if dat == 0:
                yield x1_dat[_], y1_dat[_], 0
            else:
                yield x2_dat[_], y2_dat[_], 1

layer_specifications = [2, 100, 100, 100, 1]
sess = tf.Session()
model = Model(sess, data, nEpochs=10, learning_rate=1.1e-2, layer_specifications=layer_specifications)
model.train_init()
model.train()

inferrences_1 = []
inferrences_2 = []

losses = 0
for i in range(len(t_p)-1, -1, -1):
    infer, loss = model.infer(x1_p[i], y1_p[i], 0)
    if infer >= 0.5:
        print('loss: {0} on point {1}, {2}'.format(loss, x1_p[i], y1_p[i]))
        losses = losses + 1
        inferrences_1.append('r')
    else:
        inferrences_1.append('g')
for i in range(len(t_p)-1, -1, -1):
    infer, loss = model.infer(x2_p[i], y2_p[i], 1)
    if infer >= 0.5:
        inferrences_2.append('r')
    else:
        print('loss: {0} on point {1}, {2}'.format(loss, x2_p[i], y2_p[i]))
        losses = losses + 1
        inferrences_2.append('g')

print('total losses: {}'.format(losses))

plt.scatter(x1_p, y1_p, c=inferrences_1)
plt.scatter(x2_p, y2_p, c=inferrences_2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does Tensorflow take an ensemble for the final outcome, such as averaging?

Comment: I don't believe it does.  It would not make sense in this scenario for it to do so.

Comment: If there is no convergence, it seems that the loss values of training and testing are not the same!

Comment: Not sure what's going on with the loss (training does seem a bit unstable), but you can make inferences much faster if you don't define ops every time you make a classification (with the `tf.sigmoid` call in `infer`). Can you try tracking this down to the classification changing on a specific point?